# Why does sprockets destroy my images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

This image

[image: original image]

becomes

[image: twisted]

when watched through the rails 3.1 WEBrick 131 with sprockets.

Ant idea what is occurring there? The request also takes a minute or so to finish. The smaller the image the less the destruction.

Edit: The file is served from the asset directory and no manipulation is involved.

Comment: how is the file being accessed?  Is it a static file under /public, under /assets... is it stored in a database and output directly in an image tag (with the raw data in src, etc.)?

Comment: what type of file are you trying to transfer? Jpg? Png? Bmp? Does it perform the same type of corruption with diffrent image formats?

Comment: I added to the op how the image is served. I get this result in all possible ways to access the file, without html errors and friends. The above result comes from directly [get]ting the image without any page involved.

Comment: It is independent of the file format, I get the same kind of funk (with different artefacts) with all possible formats

Comment: I'm having this problem too using webrick on a mac. does seem to be much worse as the file size gets bigger. Still only serving 82kb images and they still degrade. Anyone found a solution yet?

Comment: Does not happen on my mac, only on windows. I guess it is an encoding issue with longer requests or something like that. I need to check if it is already fixed as RC1 supposedly is out already - if not I`ll file a bug.